# How to get the name of the class predicted by keras trained model for categorical output?

Tags: keras, label, conv-neural-network

I have a trained CNN model which should predict one of 5 emotions: anger, disgust, fear, neutral or sadness.
I'm using

```
ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                      shear_range=0.1,
                      zoom_range=0.1,
                      horizontal_flip=True)
```

and

```
low_from_directory('../large-dataset-copy/training/',
                            color_mode='grayscale',
                            target_size=(48,48),
                            class_mode = 'categorical',
                            batch_size = 32)
```

for read and transform the images.

After training I don't know how to extract the correspondent class of what the model predict.
I use the next code to read and transform the image:

```
def test_data(img_path):
    img_array = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_img = cv2.resize(img_array,(48,48))
    return new_img.reshape(-1,48,48,1)

img = test_data('Abdullah_Gul_0006.jpg')
emotionClassifier = k.models.load_model('moedel.h5',compile=False)
emotion = emotionClassifier.predict(img)
print(emotion)
```

and this is the output I get ***always***: **[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]]**

Also the output from **print(test_data.class_indices)**  is {**'anger': 0, 'disgust': 1, 'fear': 2, 'neutral': 3, 'sadness': 4}**

Answer (score 0):

As the class-mode is set to "categorical" in the flow_from_directory method the results are returned in a 2D one-hot encoded label array. The result you are getting [0,1,0,0,0] means the picture label is "disgust" as that is the second one in the class_indices list.

Btw, if you are using a sequential model you should use predict_classes instead of predict to get the results.

Comment: Thanks. And also one reason for getting the same output in 90% of cases could be because the model is overfitting? The accurracy seems high. The next code **scores = emotionClassifier.evaluate(validation_data)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (emotionClassifier.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))** prints out 88%

Comment: It may be. I would also crosscheck the labels to make sure the correct information is used to train the system. Btw, if my answer helped you can accept it.

Comment: You should probably check the class imbalances in both the training and validation set too.